# Where can I find a list of libraries that I can include with Sprockets directives?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-3.2, sprockets

I want to include the [chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) library like my other js libraries in my Rails app like this in `application.js`:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

But I don't know if I just have to type `//= require chosen` and that's it.

So I tried to find a list of libraries that I can include with sprockets but I got nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need that javascript library packed as a gem. You're lucky, there [is](https://rubygems.org/gems/chosen-rails) a gem.

Add `gem chosen-rails` to your `Gemfile` and run the `bundle install`-command. Afterwards, you can use `//= require chosen-jquery` in your `application.js`-file.

For further information please visit [the github homepage of this gem](https://github.com/tsechingho/chosen-rails).

To your question. Today it's quite common to pack such librarys as `chosen` is into a gem. Just search the name of the library you are looking for on http://rubygems.org/ or even google.

If no such gem exists, you could pack one by yourself (see [this](http://prioritized.net/blog/gemify-assets-for-rails/) amazing article) or add the librarys by hand to your `vendor`-assets directory.